# cannot find symbol class GCMListenerService

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm attending to follow this tutorial:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-get-started-with-push-notifications-on-android--cms-25870

I'm using **Android Studio 2.3 Canary 2** on a Mac

But When I compile, I always get this error on my NotificationsListenerService:

```
Error:(7, 51) error: cannot find symbol class GCMListenerService
```

I followed the instructions of the tutorial as best I can.

1. I added the latest version of google-services in my project's build.gradle:

   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

build.gradle: http://pastebin.com/ZE4iqFxU

2. I added the latest version of play-services in my app's build.gradle:

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'

and also applied the plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ecaring.gcmtest"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

3. I updated the manifest with permissions, receiver, ... and created the appropriate classes.

Manifest: http://pastebin.com/ZpBNVsVi

4. I downloaded the google-services.json file from Google and added it to my app directory
5. I created the classes from the tutorial:

   - RegistrationService
   - TokenRefreshListenerService
   - NotificationsListenerService extends GcmListenerService

And updated the [Manifest](http://pastebin.com/ZpBNVsVi) each time.

6. I synced with gradle, clean the project and rebuild it multiple times. I tried different version of google-services and play-services.
7. I always get the same error:

Error:(7, 51) error: cannot find symbol class GCMListenerService

Here is the offending file:
NotificationsListenerService.java:

```
public class NotificationsListenerService extends GCMListenerService {
}
```

I tried added an import statement at the time, but the editor says it will be unused.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Lowercase `Gcm`...  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmListenerService

Comment: Of course, I made the stupidest mistake of all. Thinking I can type! Thanks all for your time.

Comment: I just checked the tutorial and it also has a lowercase Gcm, so I'm not sure what you copied

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Google Cloud Messaging` is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq) in favor of `Firebase Cloud Messaging`, so it's better to use FCM now.

As for your issue it seems that tutsplus tutorial is outdated. Use official documentation or older version of google play services.

[Set up a GCM Client App on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

[Set Up a Firebase Cloud Messaging Client App on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Comment: `play-services-gcm`  is used

Comment: @cricket_007 i didn't check pastebin, he had `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` when I was writing my answer. Will edit.

Comment: At first, I used the exact versions from the tutorial. But I had similar issues, so I google and everyone suggested using the latest version, so I changed it. Also I tried both play-services-gcm and play-services-gcm.

Comment: it seems you misspelled your class name as @cricket_007 pointed out in comment to your post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all to inform, Google Cloud Messaging is deprecated in favor of Firebase Cloud Messaging, so it's better to use FCM now.but this time not easy to implement third party (api) to send push notification is easy as like GCM.

FCM send push notification third party api using accesstoken and server key of app to create firebase